# Marching Cubes for Quadrics - Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, marching-cubes

I have tried to implement an applet showing the distinct types of [space quadrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) with the Marching Cubes library of three.js to render implicit surfaces. The shapes that appear though are not right and I guess I am not implementing the properties of `THREE.MarchingCubes` as needed. The core of the applet has the following code

```
        quadricData = {
            a11: 1,
            a22: 1,
            a33: 1,
            a12: 0,
            a13: 0,
            a23: 0,
            a1: 0,
            a2: 0,
            a3: 0,
            a: -1
        };

        quadValue = function (data, x, y, z) {
            return data.a11*x*x+
                   data.a22*y*y+
                   data.a33*z*z+
                   data.a12*2*x*y+
                   data.a13*2*x*z+
                   data.a23*2*y*z+
                   data.a1*x+
                   data.a2*y+
                   data.a3*z+
                   data.a;
        }

        var res = 50;
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            color: '#1565C0', // blue 800
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 0.8,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            flatShading: true
        } );

        quadric = new THREE.MarchingCubes( res, material );
        quadric.isolation = 0;

        for ( var k = 0 ; k < res ; k++ ) {
            for ( var j = 0 ; j < res ; j++ ) {
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < res ; i++ ) {

                var x = 8*(i-res/2)/res;
                var y = 8*(j-res/2)/res;
                var z = 8*(k-res/2)/res;

                quadric.field[ i + j*res + k*res*res ] = quadValue(quadricData,x,y,z);

                }
            }
        }
```

but the full code may be inspected [here](https://github.com/TungstenHub/tngt-threejs/blob/master/scripts/quadrics.html). I suppose that the `field` attribute has to be filled with the values of a function, but perhaps this is not the correct way to proceed. Strange effects appear, for instance, when making `a11` large, which expands the ellipsoid instead of shrinking it; the 'marching cubes grid' seems also to expand, which is sort of funny.

[image]

Many other configurations do not match the expected result. Which is the right way to use `THREE.MarchingCubes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use THREE.MarchingCubes:

- Include MarchingCubes.js via `<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/MarchingCubes.js"></script>`
- Allocate the volume with resolution R, which will be a voxel cube with resolution R x R x R, via `V = new THREE.MarchingCubes( R, material )`
- Fill in the voxel values, which are a linear array of float values.  The index for a voxel at location [X,Y,Z] is (X + (Y * R) + ( Z * R * R)).  Set the values via `V.field[ i + j*R + k*R*R ] = f`
- Set the `isolation` value.  The displayed volume will be all voxels less than this value, so this could all be called iso-surface value.  Set the value via `V.isolation = s`.

It seems your code is working correctly.  Increasing a11 does reduce the volume in the x dimension as expected.

[image]

The only thing I noticed is the code multiplying `a12` and `a13` and `a23` by 2.  If a quadric equation is expressed as:

Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Exz + Fyz + Gz + Hy + Iz + J = 0

And the calculation is: `data.a11*x*x + data.a22*y*y + data.a33*z*z + data.a12*2*x*y + data.a13*2*x*z + data.a23*2*y*z + data.a1*x + data.a2*y + data.a3*z + data.a`, then it seems to multiply D E and F by two for no reason?

Otherwise, was there a bug you've resolved since posting the question?  Or could you be more specific about the problem?

**Bug report:**  There's a [bug report 14060 logged against three.js here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14060#issuecomment-388894564).  As of May 2018, with three.js version r92, it appears the Marching Cubes library is working in (1) Firefox in Windows and MacOS, (2) Safari on MacOS.  It appears buggy in Firefox on Linux, and in Chrome on any system.  Turning off flat shading may resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is funny, but my code does not work properly; I have added a gif for clarity. If you download the code from GitHub, do you get right results? Perhaps it depends on the browser or something else? In https://cdn.rawgit.com/TungstenHub/tngt-threejs/master/scripts/quadrics.html there still are wrong results. As for the 2 factor, it has to do with the coefficients coming from a symmetric matrix: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html

Comment: In Firefox version >= 59 on Windows 7, the results look correct to me.

Comment: I've tried in Firefox 60 and it does not work, also clearing browsing data and in incognito mode. Incrementing a11 makes the ellipsoid in the x direction. Could you upload a picture of a working example? Very funny indeed

Comment: Edited with GIF.  Don't think the code has any modifications other than removing the multiply-by-two, which I agree shouldn't make a difference.  You don't see any problems with the demos [here](https://webglsamples.org/blob/blob.html) or [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_marchingcubes.html)?

Comment: Really, I can't believe it. In your GIF it works perfectly. How does https://cdn.rawgit.com/TungstenHub/tngt-threejs/master/scripts/quadrics.html appear to you? Could you check this link? If it appears ok for you, perhaps it is a bug in the library; it has no sense that there are different results for the same code. I've opened an issue in https://discourse.threejs.org/t/marching-cubes-for-quadrics/2823 and I'll draw their attention about this funny fact. Thank you very much!!

Comment: It is working the same for me, at the [link you provided](https://cdn.rawgit.com/TungstenHub/tngt-threejs/master/scripts/quadrics.html), meaning, it seems to work fine.  For your question on threejs.org (and here) I'd recommend including details of your browser, hardware, and operating system, and to try on a few different setups.  As with any browser-based technology it's important to stay alert for inconsistencies across different environments.

Comment: Actually a (strange) bug: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14060#issuecomment-388894564 you may include this in your answer in case it helps other people. Thanks again!!

Comment: Added bug report details.  Please let me know if you see any inaccuracy.